# Selecting nuget.org as the source when installing AWS lambda tools in an Azure pipeline

Tags: aws-lambda, azure-devops, yaml

Im using the below task to install AWS.Lambda.Tools in my pipeline, however I can't get it to use nuget.org as the source and it continues to try and use my internal feed.

```yaml
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'sudo dotnet tool install --tool-path=/usr/bin --add-source=https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json Amazon.Lambda.Tools --version 4.0.0'
```

I receive the following error

```
sudo dotnet tool install --tool-path=/usr/bin --add-source=https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json Amazon.Lambda.Tools --version 4.0.0
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/8dc54544-e317-472d-99dc-2345f6558e42.sh
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.102/NuGet.targets(131,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://internalfeed.pkgs.....
```

How can I resolve this error so that the script runs successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing in my side and found that this script would run successfully using Ubuntu agents if you don't configure a nuget.config with packageSource reference to a private nuget feed/Azure Devops artifacts.

This is a known issue reported here: https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-azure-devops/pull/355 and https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-azure-devops/issues/316.